# Sphinx best way WHERE and UPDATE on MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, subquery, sphinx

I kind used in MySQL query:

```
UPDATE 
    Tovar
    Tovar INNER JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM (.....
            SELECT * FROM 
        ....) as `tmp` ON 
            CONCAT(' ',Tovar.drugApt,' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ',tmp.`P`,' %') 
            OR IF(
                tmp.line is not null,
                CONCAT(' ',Tovar.drugApt,' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ',tmp.`line`,' %'),
                0
            ) OR IF(
                tmp.invert is not null,
                CONCAT(' ',Tovar.drugApt,' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ',tmp.`invert`,' %'),
                0
            ) 
        WHERE 
            Tovar.idPreparat IS NULL 
            AND Tovar.md5Drug <> 0xF7270DB295EE1770CAD49A0CB0C40D91
    ) tmpf ON tmpf.idT = Tovar.id
SET Tovar.idPreparat = tmpf.id;
```

As is well-known mysql doesn't use index:

```
WHERE LIKE '%....%'
```

Slow performance.
Then I have decided to try Fulltext index in mysql, but I don't accept performance time.
Now I have passed to Sphinx. Since I work in him for the first time, I ask to help.

***table Tovar:***

id, idPreparat, idCountry, idManufacturer, drugA, countryA, manfA

***table Preparat:***

id, prep

*Tovar.idPreparat associated with Preparat.id*

I create two Index in Sphinx:

```
source tovar : apt
{
    sql_query       =  SELECT Tovar.id as id, Tovar.drugApt as drug,Tovar.countryApt as country,Tovar.manfApt as manf FROM Tovar
    sql_field_string = drug
    sql_field_string = country
    sql_field_string = manf
    sql_ranged_throttle = 100
}

source prep : apt
{
    sql_query       =  SELECT  id, prep FROM Preparat
    sql_field_string = cn
    sql_ranged_throttle = 100
}
```

I need to put down idPreparat where idPreparat IS NULL there. Check will be on the column drugA.
Example (everything is done by me, to make it clear):
[image]
[image]

What best way of realization of my problem? Thank!

Comment: To clarify this. You trying to use sphinx, to help optimize a mysql UPDATE? Ie sphinx does hold its data 'outside' mysql (ie they are seperate servers) - so does take a quite a bit of work to sync them. Frankly the only way can see this haveing a hope of working is via SphinxSE. SO can write SQL queries that (interally) run Sphinx Queries. Getting SphinxSE working is often not trivial https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-sphinxse/